# Can you run javascript server side on ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic, azure-web-app-service

In the days of ASP, we wrote all the server side backend in javascript (JScript), when most people were using VBScript.  It was an old JS dialect, but worked flawlessly.

However, we cannot find out if this possible with ASP.NET.  All the examples are C#, and we have all our server side codebase in JS. yes, we could run it in Node or Rhino, but we would like to run it on Azure webapps which are .net.

This page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_server-side_JavaScript_implementations
Has a list of server side javascript engines, but ASP.NET seems to be missing.

Comment: Theoretically you can have many languages compile down to the CIL that the .NET platform can run. However in practice, only C#, VB.NET, and F# do that. I'm unaware of any modern method for running JS in .NET. There are bridge services to Node, but that's more for niche interop scenarios. Node is the accepted way of running JS server side. Why do you think that you can't run Node in Azure web app? [They have a tutorial for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/).

Comment: Microsoft's old ASP JScript and NodeJS use the same base language, but not the same system calls etc - you'll find you can't just plonk it in a NodeJS environment and run it straight away, it would be likely to need fairly significant alterations. As mason says, you can run NodeJS in Azure, but it's still very unlikely to be a straight-up lift-and-shift of your ASP code. You'll need to plan for a decent amount of effort in re-coding and re-testing. If you want to move to Azure you might almost be better off containerising an environment which can run ASP directly.

Comment: Although having said all that, from a quick bit of googling this blog reckons you make can make Classic ASP work in Azure app service: https://edi.wang/post/2019/7/17/run-classic-asp-on-windows-10-and-azure-app-service ... I haven't tried it but it sounds like it would be worth your time to investigate.

Comment: @ADyson they're not asking to run Classic ASP, they want to use JScript in ASP.Net. For what it's worth Classic ASP will run in the Azure Cloud app because I've done it before.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful comments.  So I think we are saying that ASP.NET/.NET/.Net CORE (I dont really know what the differences are) cant run javascirpt/JScript or any flavour of javascript

Comment: @Lankymart yes but if you read carefully they are only asking that because they've assumed that classic ASP will not run in Azure, and the ultimate aim is to run the application in Azure. It's kind of an X-Y problem, or near enough.

Comment: @JohnLittle well it _could_ in theory, if someone wrote a version which would compile to .NET CIL (intermediate language). But there are no implementations right now. But as a couple of us have noted, since you say you want to run the code in Azure web apps, then you can (although it's badly documented) actually just run your Classic ASP application in Azure as-is, without converting to .NET

Comment: According to Wikipedia jscript on .net exists and is called  jscript.net. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET however the only example is command line not sever side as part of web app

Comment: There'd be nothing much stopping you using it for a web app then in theory, although without ready-made templates etc it'd be a lot of work to do an MVC app or similar. This page has a (very) simple example of using it for an ASMX web service, for example:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-jscript-net/ . But again, I really think you should stop worrying about it, and just _try to run your classic-ASP/JScript code in Azure directly_

Answer (score 1):

I've never used it myself and not sure how well it is supported these days:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET

Comment: Thanks. I saw this, and tried to get it working, but could not.

Comment: Never tried this either but perhaps https://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/

Might be of help?

Comment: I personally think it'd be awesome if Microsoft revived JScript.NET and make it a great contender to Node and Deno for back-end apps.

Comment: @noseratio Agreed MS should reboot classic ASP as it is server side JavaScript way before node

Comment: @silver, I also think a modern reboot of JScript.NET - if backed by Microsoft - might overall be a great scripting language with access to all .NET API. It could be a viable alternative to PowerShell.

Comment: @noseratio Why can't we do both :)

Comment: @silver, oh if only we could... Then I would've asked for a reboot of Windows Mobile as well :)